# Is there an internet browser application that runs on mono?

Tags: browser, mono

I am using KeePass on my Mac, it runs on Mono. However, there is no copy paste between mono and Mac apps. So, I am looking for a mono based internet browser, hoping that copy paste within the mono framework works fine.

This question does not belong to SU, because I am willing to compile the application from the sources, if it is necessary - slightly beyond the SU scope, isn't it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried KeepassX? The password file format should be compatible...

Comment: I'm pretty certain Mono apps on OS X are capable of copy/paste. Otherwise MonoDevelop would be a complete flop and it's not from what I've seen.

I suspect it's a problem with KeePass itself. Try KeePassX as Piskvor mentioned.

Comment: @Piskvor, KeepassX does not support the new format of KeePass 2, which I am using at work.

Comment: @alimbada - Well, surprise, surprise. It does not work. There is even a bug open on it - http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-bugs@lists.ximian.com/msg65964.html. Anyway, I have iMac at home and copy/paste works fine between native apps, but not between mono and native ones, so I personally confirm this bug.

Comment: There is more to it than being a "Mono" app.  MonoDevelop is written in GTK#, which is much more mature and tested, so c&p works there.  KeyPass is written using Winforms, which is still missing features on OSX like c&p.

Comment: @jpobst So what you are saying is that even if I find such a browser, there is no guarantee that c&p will work between it and KeePass?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even read what you are trying to do.  Lemme stop you there.  There is no Mono based internet browser, and I am 99.99% sure there never will be.  A simpler solution than writing an entire browser from scratch to get copy and paste would be to fix the copy and paste bug in Mono on OSX.

Comment: @jpobst I agree with you, however the bug is still there... 
BTW, there is this - http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser

Comment: /WebBrowser is a thin wrapper around Gecko (the core of Firefox).  It lets Gecko handle c&p instead of doing it through Mono.  Also, it doesn't run on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeePass issue referred to in the question is that Windows Forms on the Mac version of Mono has a bug that prevents copy and paste between applications. It is still a real bug. It does not affect GTK# apps like MonoDevelop or MonoMac and Cocoa# apps.

The bug report is [here](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=533291#add_comment).

Since the issue is Windows Forms, it would not help to have a Mono based browser with a MonoMac or GTK# GUI.

In fact, it would not help to have a Windows Forms based browser since the bug is that you cannot cut and paste between windows, not just between Windows Forms and other GUI frameworks.

You can easily confirm this by simply running two copies of the application attached as part of the bug report above. You will see that you can cut and paste within a single app but not between them. This is when you are trying to cut and paste between two instances of the EXACT same app even.

So, to answer the actual question, I am not aware of a Mono based browser. You could easily build one yourself with the Mono.WeBrowser or System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser classes. I would be tempted to whip one up but it will not help with this specific issues.

To address the actual need of the original poster. Having a Mono-based browser will not get you any closer to cutting and pasting from KeePass until the Mono bug is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer.